# Folder schema in PHP

Tags: php, schema, directory

Ok, i am new to this and i'm trying to make a real simple project just to test my ability.
I just came up with this schema in mind and i don't really know if it's a pattern or something and i'd like to get some suggestions about it and how to improve it.

```
index.php  # This manage the $_GET['page'] var and load some basic stuff
app/  # Here's the logic part, the pages included in index.php, they do some stuffs and then call templates to output the HTML page
config/  # Here we put some configurations file such as database.con.php or board.con.php which contain an extension or the array $cf
lang/  # Same way of configurations, we have something like en.lang.php or it.lang.php and inside there is an array called $lang 
lib/class/  # Contains all the classes
lib/set/ # Contains sets of functions, such as error.set.php or file.set.php
theme/ # Contains template file that got called from app files
```

Will i stuck with this schema? Is there anything that can be improved/changed?

Comment: Update to the profile loop: `while(true) { if(empty($beer)) { get_a_beer();  $cm->roll(); } drink($beer); }`

Comment: @Steve, reviewed my code. Add some more cool stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your document root (for the webserver) in app, or are we looking at it? Looks like you might already know this but you should consider keeping folders like lib and config out of your document root.

Comment: document root is in / not in /app/. Why is it so dangerous to put libraries and config there?

Comment: one time, something went wonky on my server, and PHP stopped being processed by Apache, and I could see all of the code for every page. not sure why this happened, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

That looks alright.

Keep in mind that you should name and place your classes in a way to facilitate auto loading.

It'd also be useful keeping everything but `index.php` and `theme/` (if it contains assets such as CSS/JavaScript/images) above the document root.